# Change the path address in a text file by shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

In my Bash script, I have to change a name to a path address(new address) in a text file:
(MYADDREES) change to ( `/home/run1/c1` ) and save it as new file.

I did like this: defined a new variable = new address  and tried to replace it in previous address in text file.

I use sed but it has problem.

My script was:

```
#!/bin/bash
# To debug
set -x
x=`pwd`
echo $x
sed "s/MYADDRESS/$x/g" < sample1.txt > new.txt
exit
```

Comment: Can you please describe the problem that you have with sed?

Comment: please edit your question to show what is in `sample1.txt`, what you want to appear in `new.txt` and what is the problem with the current solution. Good luck.

Comment: Instead of "sed "s/MYADDRESS/$x/g" < sample1.txt > new.txt" it is better to do it like "sed "s/MYADDRESS/$x/g" sample1.txt > new.txt" since there is not need to redirect output into sed (it automatically reads the file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `pwd` is likely to contain `/` characters, making your sed expression look something like `s/MYADDRESS//home/user/somewhere/`. This makes it impossible for `sed` to sort out what should be replaced with what. There are two solutions:

Use a different delimiter for sed:

```
sed "s,MYADDRESS,$x,g" < sample1.txt > new.txt
```

...although this will have the same problem if the current path contains a comma character or something else that is a special character for `sed`, so the **more robust** approach is to use `awk` instead:

```
awk -v curdir="$(pwd)" '{ gsub("MYADDRESS", curdir); print }' < sample1.txt > new.txt
```

Comment: Your `sed` response is the proper response, absent the initial redirect. This is what the stream editor was designed to do. `sed` is far more ubiquitous than whatever `gsub` is.

Comment: awk is just about as ubiquitous as sed. `gsub(pattern, replacement)` in awk does the same as `s/pattern/replacement/g` in sed, but without the latter's sanitation problems.